# pandas plot axes limits too tight

Tags: python, pandas, plot, axes

When using pandas to plot the x-axis limits are chosen to be exactly the data range.  That's not what I want - I wanted nice rounded up values the same as matplotlib would do.
If I plot directly with mpl instead of pandas.plot, I get the nice axes ranges I want.
Any good solutions?

Comment: `df.plot()` returns the axes, so you could fiddle with parameters after the fact, e.g. `ax = df.plot()` followed by `ax.set_xlim(...)` or similar.

Comment: Sure, but I really just wanted the plot to set the axis automatically.  Now the first and last data point are clipped by the plot edges (I'm plotting with markers, and the markers are right at the axes limits).